# Tag "Android" e a syntax highlight para o seu código "java"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, syntax-highlighting

Reparei numa série de perguntas com a tag [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) cujas mesmas contem código mas por não existir a tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) a *syntax highlight* não funciona.

Tendo código, estive a adicionar a tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).
Claro que é preciso andar a fazer retag caso o autor da pergunta não tenha conhecimento desta questão.

Para evitar isto, será possível associar a *syntax highlight* para a tag [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) com as especificações da tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) ?

Se inconveniente devido ao uso da tag [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) em cenários que não envolvem código, como podemos lidar com esta questão?

Comment: Uma nota é que o código pode também ser XML. A questão deveria especificar uma linguagem, de qualquer forma.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Exacto. Entretanto lembrei-me que a solução também pode passar por actualizar a wiki da tag Android para dar conta que devem usar a tag "java" ou "xml" ou "whatever" em conjunto com a tag android para melhor identificar o problema e permitir ao sistema que assuma a formatação correcta.